# Exclude Elements from being replaced with cufon?

Tags: javascript, html, cufon

If I have set cufon to replace all h1 elements with a font, can I exclude elements with specific classes?

So for example, cufon replaces all h1 elements on a page except for elements with a class of 'nocufon'.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this, but this should work

```
cufon.replace('h1:not(.nocufon)', {fontFamily:'myfont'});
```

For this to work, you may also have to include jQuery or MooTools, or some other supported selector. https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/usage